# JAX-WS - multiple web services - SOAP handlers not working

Tags: soap, jax-ws, soaphandler

I am working on a project that requires connecting to two different web services, so I have two web clients as dependencies (as JARs). 
My problem is that only the handlers from one of the services are being called, the handlers from the other one are completely ignored. Both of the ws have a handler chain that works correctly in separate projects, but when combined, only one works. 
I am defining the handler chain in handlers.xml.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Difficult to troubleshoot with only the symptom described. Post code samples, particularly of the handler chain setup - are you using programmatic or declarative handler definition? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I was defining the handlers chain in two handlers.xml files, one for each of the services that I was using and the handlers classes and handlers.xml were included in the client jars. I moved the handlers definition in the web application, placed the handlers.xml in the classpath, defined handlers for both of the services in same file (using a condition to determine which handler should be executed) and the problem was solved.
I don't if the solution is correct or very elegant, but I'm not very familiar with SOAP handlers. If you have suggestions, feel free to comment/answer. Thanks!